# Are there any ads on the SE network?

Tags: discussion, advertising

OK, I hope this question is not that stupid, but this question has been haunting me for more than a short time. I did not see any ads on the Stack Exchange network, is it because I missed something or are there actually no ads on SE?

Comment: Do you have AdBlock running? Generally signed in users in SE get very little ads and some of the ones they do are for open source community projects. Most ads I run into when signed in in SO are for SO careers. Try going to Stack Overflow in an incognito tab or logged out and read a question.

Comment: By "SE family site", do you mean the SE site on [genealogy.se], or the entile SE family of sites?

Comment: @JanDvorak The whole SE family sites

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No, I don't have AdBlock, maybe the ads are just too cute.

Comment: What about NoScript? Most of the ads are loaded via JavaScript from third-party sites (such as adzerk.net), so unless you allow scripts from those sites, you won't see any ads (except maybe some for Careers 2.0, since those are loaded from *.stackoverflow.com / sstatic.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, there were ads only on the three oldest sites in the network: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/). You'll see fewer ads if you visit while logged into an account with [more than 200 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). Nowadays some of the other high-traffic sites have ads; see [What sites have advertisements enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243364/what-sites-have-advertisements-enabled/243521#243521) for a list.

Some sites have ads chosen by the community, via threads such as [this one](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/community-promotion-ads-2014). These are present on graduated sites (i.e. sites other than the SO/SF/SU original trilogy and “special” sites such as this meta site and other than the young sites that have a beta status) as well as SF and SU.
SO has [something similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) with the restriction that only ads soliciting developers to participate in open-source projects are allowed.

Comment: Note that there's an update on this topic here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243521/165581

Answer (score 3):

There are ads shown to low rep users (see screenshot) but most of these are removed for users [above 200 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). Meta sites do not carry ads even for low rep users.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I see an ad on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AveMaleficum Most ads seem to be for Careers 2.0, which don't look that much like ads because Careers 2.0 is internal to stack exchange and so look "like they belong"

Comment: By the way, I am living in China, maybe GFW does something good sometimes.

Comment: @AveMaleficum There are some advantages, although stack exchange does do a good job of only including high quality adverts

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are ads. [At 200 reputation, you see less of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) - that should be enough evidence they *exist*, though you might not be seeing them for a number of reasons on your side.