# What sites have advertisements enabled?

Tags: support, advertising

Apparently Drupal.SE has ads:

[image]

Which doesn't seems to be mentioned in the [advertising program](https://stackexchange.com/mediakit) list. Are there sites that have ads enabled yet not documented (apart from the trilogy)?

---

#### Other sites found:

#### Ask Ubuntu

[image]

#### Game Development

[image]

#### Site formerly known as Nothing To Install

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **Update: All sites are now running adverts for the next 6 months.**
>
> See [We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network)
>
> Unlike the message below, the same rules **do not** apply to these sites. They **no longer** aim to keep all advertising as relevant as possible. They **do** work with ad networks.

The last media kit update appears to have removed the additional sites that we've added advertising to - this has been corrected.

The [sites that now accept advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287242/) are:

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com)
- [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)
- [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
- [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

The same rules apply to these sites. We aim to keep all advertising as relevant as possible. We do not work with ad networks or sell inventory at remnant rates.

Comment: FYI - The media kit doesn't permit me to select any of these non-trilogy sites for the self-serve option. Is that intentional to keep buys less than $5k from these sites or might I not be looking in the correct place at https://selfserve-stackexchange.com

Comment: @bmike - As self-serve is a new product for us (September 2014), we intentionally decided to limit it to the trilogy for now as we know inventory availability would not be an issue. As the sites above grow, we will consider adding them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Very awesome. Sounds like you're off to the races. Best of luck with the continuing evolution of the platform and the company. Thanks for the reply - I'm very new to the terms and existence of the ad program.

Comment: I just looked around Arquade and Unix/Linux a bit and saw no advertisements.  Where are they?

Comment: @MichaelHardy As we make every effort to only show ads that are relevant and of interest to a particular site, there are some sites that accept advertising, but do not currently have any ads running yet.