# Does the reduced advertising privilege exist on non-trilogy sites that carry ads?

Tags: support, privileges, advertising

From [What sites have advertisements enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243364/what-sites-have-advertisements-enabled) we know that besides SO, SU and SF, a dozen of sites accept advertising. On a few of those ads are already up and running.

Thankfully, SO/SU/SF have a "reduced ads" privilege at 200 reputation:

> [image]

But the newer ad-carrying sites do not (screenshot from Drupal)

> [image]

Does the "reduced ads" privilege  exist on those sites? If no, why? If yes, why isn't it documented?

Comment: Drupal should have a reduced spam privilege instead. [not my joke]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The privilege *exists* everywhere. But on most sites, it's hidden and notifications for earning it are suppressed. Doesn't make much sense to tell folks about a privilege that doesn't actually *do* anything.

Just because we're willing to sell ads on a site doesn't mean you'll ever see them... And note that the privilege suppresses the full-width ads on question pages, not the sidebar ads.

That said, if we forget to enable this on a site that *is* hosting (and therefore suppressing) such ads, don't hesitate to post a bug report.

Comment: Does the lack of privilege in the Help Center list itself constitute a bug? I saw banner ads on [four sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243364/259867), none of which have "reduced ads" in their privilege list.

Comment: Yup - report it.