# Mark 200 reputation in the privilege ladder

Tags: feature-request, reputation, area-51, privileges, association-bonus

Despite being an important mark, the reaching of 200 reputation is not marked in the privilege ladder. The achievement grant in fact some privileges around the SE network

- Qualification for an association bonus
- Counting you in as an experienced user in the commitment phase of the Area51 process

The privilege is clearly of the "milestone" type, it could be named something like **experienced user** (that's the terminology used in Area51).

Comment: Can you define what the "privilege ladder" is? If you're talking about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), it looks like it's already there, no?

Comment: It is exactly that what you've guessed. To my surprise, on chemistry.se the 200 mark is not or no longer there. No "reduced adds" as a privilege.—https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Interestingly, it's there on [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Hmm it's there on [Arqade.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) too. Does Chemistry just not have ads?

Comment: Asked a question on the chemistry meta about this. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/why-is-there-no-reduced-adds-privilege-at-200-reputation-on-this-site

Comment: Got an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a privilege at that step of the ladder, however I happened to consult the help page of a site where this privilege is hidden. The privilege is "[reduce ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246562/does-the-reduced-advertising-privilege-exist-on-non-trilogy-sites-that-carry-ads/246563#246563)". By nature, it applies only to sites with advertising enabled.

Comment: I think that the reduce ads privilege should be granted to everyone at 0 rep.Twice.

Comment: Unfortunately it is revoked at reputation 1 unless you are Chuck Norris.