# Java File API ad on Gaming.SE?

Tags: bug, advertising

This ad showed up on Arqade (Gaming). The ad itself is fine, it just seems *really* out of place.

[image]

Is it really suppose to show up on a site for video games?

Comment: That is odd... I'd always thought that the only sites that get non-SE ads are the big three... not any of the smaller sites.... [yep, that's right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223158/are-there-any-ads-on-the-se-network).

Comment: @Catija Other sites have accepted ads for quite a while now. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243521 (though I don't know if that list is still up-to-date).

Comment: @Catija Not to brag about it, but Gaming is currently No. 4 on the entire network in terms of traffic http://i.stack.imgur.com/hCwYZ.png. It would be mildly insulting for the site to *not* receive any ads

Comment: @YiJiang according to [the SE all sites page](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) when sorted by traffic, SF is ranked above Arqade.

Comment: Arqade *is* on the ad rotation list in general, but that ad in particular does seem like it got lost on its way to Stack Overflow. I passed this along to the ads team and they'll take a look at what happened there.

Comment: @angussidney When I look at that page, it puts Arqade above SF by about 1k visits. So it's close.